# Determine whether the rows of A form a linearly dependent set.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If so, find the coefficients involved involved in a linear combination of rows that is zero.

[image]
;

(my solution:)
Det(A)=0 so rows of A form a linearly dependent set.
and a[3 2 -1 -1]+b[2 1 1 2]+c[-1 3 2 -9]+d[4 -5 2 25] = [0 0 0 0]
where a,b,c,d are all equal to 0.
(details:
[image]
)

I'm confused that based on the theorem A's rows form a l.d. set, but the coefficients are all equal to 0 and that means they are linear independent.

which part did I work wrong?

Comment: How did you prove that $a,b,c,d$ are all $0$? If you show the proof we can try to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @KaboMurphy OK I've edited it.

Comment: Start with variables p,q,r,s in the final column and perform only row operations; if the rows are indeed linearly dependent, you will end up with a zero row, and the coefficients of p,q,r,s are the a,b,c,d you needed. However, something must have gone wrong in your attempt: either $det(A)$ is not zero or the computation to arrive at the 1s on the diagonal went wrong somewhere. Check both, and add more detail to your question if you're confused!

Comment: I only get 3 LI rows when I do the row reduction. I guess you've made a slip but as you don't show your working I can't tell.

Comment: I found my computation is wrong and there's indeed only 3 LI rows. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the Gaussian elimination, you indeed get non-zero solution:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  3 & 2 &-1 & 4 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 3 &-5 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 &-9 &25 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  3 & 2 &-1 & 4 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 3 &-5 & 0 \\
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 2 &-9 &25 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  0 & 5 & 5 &10 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 & 7 &-1 & 0 \\
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-11&23 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
  0 & 5 & 5 &10 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 & 7 &-1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-11&23 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 & 7 &-1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-11&23 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 4 &-7 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 &-12&21 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 &-1 &-2 &-2 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 4 &-7 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 &-1 & 0 &-\frac{22}4 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 &\frac{15}4 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-\frac74 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 & 0 & 0 &-\frac74 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 &\frac{15}4 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-\frac74 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

The result of the above computations is that the vector $(7,-15,7,4)$ is the solution. (And all solutions are precisely the scalar multiples of this vector.)

You can also check this with some software tool, for example, [using WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B3%2C2%2C-1%2C4%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C3%2C-5%7D%2C%7B-1%2C1%2C2%2C2%7D%2C%7B-1%2C2%2C-9%2C25%7D%7D). Or you can check by hand that the linear combinations of the given vectors with these coefficients indeed gives zero.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant [is indeed 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B3%2C2%2C-1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B-1%2C3%2C2%2C-9%7D%2C%7B4%2C-5%2C2%2C25%7D%7D) so the mistake must be in the row reduction part:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2 & -1 & -1\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
-1 & 3 & 2 & -9\\
4 & -5 & 2 & 25\end{bmatrix}\to\dots ?$$